# Do Super Jumps count toward your total when in a race?

Tags: burnout-paradise, achievements

In Burnout Paradise, there are several progressions you can make in the game, such as smashing through shortcuts, finding super jumps, and driving through certain billboards.  When you perform these tasks, you get a progression indicator (e.g. 33/400).

When you are in a race, takedown, or any other game mode outside of free roam and perform one of these progressions, you do not see the indicator on screen.  Does it still count toward your total?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I confirmed that yes, you do indeed add to your counts for smashes, billboards and super jumps during a racing event. Just as [ChrisF stated in his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/do-super-jumps-count-toward-your-total-when-in-a-race/1402#1402), a notification appears in the bottom left corner indicating your progression for one of the events mentioned above.

[image: burnout paradise smashes progress]

Comment: Told you it's been a while since I played and I do get my left & right confused from time to time, which is why I'm not that good at racing games ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it does. It's been a while since I played, but I seem to remember seeing a small message appear in the bottom right of the screen when smashing a short cut.

Unfortunately I'm now at the stage when finding a new one of these is less likely so it hasn't happened recently.

The only way to be sure would be to find a jump or a short cut you haven't completed on the route of a race, make a note of your current totals, do the race taking the short cut or jump and then see if the total had increased at the end of the race.