# Do smashed billboards count toward your total progress during Showtime?

Tags: burnout-paradise

In Burnout Paradise smashing through red billboards or yellow shortcut gates usually shows a progress indicator for how many you've smashed. However, there's no progress notification if you smash a billboard during the Showtime crash mode. (And no, it's not in the [bottom left corner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1417/181240))

Do billboards smashed during the Showtime crash mode count towards your license progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Smashing a billboard during Showtime mode does not count towards progression.

Looking at the Driver Detail pages, I found that the billboard progress counter did not increase after smashing a red billboard in Showtime mode. Additionally, the "smashed" billboard respawned in unbroken form when I drove back to it's location after exiting Showtime.

[image]